# Want from one collection based on another collection document array element

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am stuck and need help to get data from another collection based array element from another collection.

My collections are as  --

```
programs.dbs -- 
{
 "_id": ObjectId("61c8f42ec63e700b415b4bed"),
"name": "Java",
"description": "this is a dummy information",
"instructor": ["61c8f6d7e690fc413a075e15", "61c8f6d7e690fc413a071e15", "61c8f0d7e690fc413a071e15"]
}

instructor.dbs --
{
 "_id": ObjectId("61c8f6d7e690fc413a075e15"),
"name": "Instrctor1",
"description": "this is a dummy Instructor",
},

{
 "_id": ObjectId("61c8f6d7e690fc413a071e15"),
"name": "Instrctor2",
"description": "this is a dummy Instructor",
},

{
 "_id": ObjectId("61c8f0d7e690fc413a071e15"),
"name": "Instrctor3",
"description": "this is a dummy Instructor",
}
```

My query is to find one instructor information based on collection A instructor Array element.
I have tried to use this query but getting empty result -

```
    db.getCollection('programs.dbs').aggregate([{$lookup:{from:'instructor.dbs',localField:'instructor',foreignField:"_id",as:'instructors'}}])
```

Immediate help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mongoose maybe the [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method can work.

Comment: I have checked this query in mongodb directly and getting empty result

Answer (score 0):

Your array of instructors should not reference the IDs as strings but as ObjectId(...)

So you would need to have:

```
"instructor": [ObjectId("61c8f6d7e690fc413a075e15"), ObjectId("61c8f6d7e690fc413a071e15"), ObjectId("61c8f0d7e690fc413a071e15")]
```